# The appearance of a gapless phase mode in Landau Ginzburg theory of charged superconductor

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, superfluidity

My question is simply: Why do the Landau Ginzburg(LG) theory of superconductors describe a phase mode which is ungapped/massless when it should be promoted to the plasma frequency?

I will try to describe my view of the problem briefly:

The LG theory has shown to be a successful (phenomenological) theory describing both conventional and unconventional superconductors(SC), charged and uncharged (superfluids). The LG equation describes space (and time) dependence of the order parameter, that is, collective excitations.

On the other hand we have the success of BCS theory for the conventional (charged) superconductors. The BSC reduced Hamiltonian only describe single-particle excitations. Collective excitations do exist, but we neglect them because they are gapped. The amplitude mode of the order ("Higgs" mode) is trivially gaped but the phase mode(originally the Goldstone mode) acquires its gap/mass from the Coulomb interaction (which pushes the mass to the plasma frequency). In the neutral superfluid this doesn't happen and Goldstone mode remains.

Why is it then that the phase-mode is described ungapped in the LG theory? I never seen this being discussed properly anywhere, but there is of course the possibility that I missed something crucial.

To my knowledge the massless phase-mode has important implications for the analysis of superconducting phenomena, so I find this issue very essential.

Comment:

The gapless phase-mode renders SC only quasi long-ranged ordered in 2D. However in 2D the plasmon is no longer gaped, which I guess would lead to a ungapped phase mode for thin or layered samples(even with the Coulomb interaction included)? This would then explain the applicability of the LG theory with gapless phase-mode for these compounds. But this would not explain why LG theory is successful in describing conventional 3D superconductors as well.

EDIT:

I would like to clarify one thing: Of course there is a difference between the charged LG and uncharged, the coupling to the gauge field in the charged case leads to the Higgs effect. In this picture the phase is "gauged away", however often the phase is left and in some limits the XY model is considered.

Comment: I don't understand the question. In a charged SC, the Goldstone mode is gapped by the (Anderson) Higgs mechanism. In a neutral SC, it is not. So in the latter case, one use a GL theory for ungapped phase mode. What's the problem then ?

Comment: @Adam. This is not a question about the uncharged case, it's about the presens of phase in the charged case. The question isn't clear I am working on rephrasing it (I am confused, so it is part of the problem). To me it seems like the gauge invariant phase do give a massless excitation.

Comment: Indeed, would you please give a few more details of what you call the gapless mode in GL model ? At least references should be added. Thanks in advance.